# Whatsapp does not open. Error - fix net::err_unknown_url_scheme

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I need to open whatsapp when a user wants to order a product. Unfortunately, I encountered this error, I tried solutions from similar questions, but unfortunately - no result. I will show you the current version of my code, maybe you can find an error there and point it out, I will be grateful to you for that.

Note, whatsapp I open from webview.

Here is my link opening code -

```
_launchURL(String url) async {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
  }
```

Here is my code to handle links that start with whatsapp... -

```
webViewController
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) async {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://wa.me/996996969696')) {
               List<String> urlSplitted = request.url.split("&text=");
              
              String phone = "996996969696";
              String message = urlSplitted.last.toString().replaceAll("%20", " ");

              await _launchURL("https://wa.me/$phone/?text=testText}");
              // await _launchURL("https://wa.me/$phone/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}");

              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            } 
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
```

There is one more detail, at first it works well, but after a couple of seconds an error screen appears (screenshots below)
[image: error]
[image: true]

I also want to show you my permissions in the manifest -

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app makes calls -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app sends emails -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Webview version - ^4.2.0

Launch_url version - ^6.1.12

PS: Also, the wire to remove the line - `mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication`, but this did not bring any result

Comment: Try with removing the `mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication`

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Unfortunately, it didn't help. Could you upvote a question if you find it interesting? Or perhaps you have other solutions?